# Issues sending mail from SMTP Server

Tags: coldfusion, sendmail, coldfusion-9

I am a PHP Developer trying to learn ColdFusion and facing a simple but confusing problem. 
I am sending email using the `cfmail` tag as follows:

```
<cfmail from = "abc@domain.com" 
        to = "sushilk@domain.com" 
        subject = "Testing mail" 
        server = "192.---.--.--" 
        password = "----" 
        port = "--" 
        username = "abc@domain.com">
```

It works great when `from="abc@domain.com"` and `username="abc@domain.com"`, both have the same values. But if I use `from="abc11@domain.com"` the mail send fails and gets stored in  CF Admin. Do I have to use the same from address as to SMTP username?

Comment: ColdFusion does not have that limitation but perhaps your email account does. Does your "abc@domain.com" account have the ability to send email as user "abc11@domain.com"? What is the error that is being logged when it fails?

Comment: Yes both emails has ability to send mails, as they are working emails. It does not show any error, just get saved to undelivered mails to CF Admin.

Comment: You don't need a username attribute unless you are authenticating with the SMTP server. Have you tried removing it entirely?

Comment: @SushilKandola - No, Miguel-F was asking if the first account has permission to send mails *using* the second account's information (ie impersonation). You can use the [`debug` attribute](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f8e.html) to help troubleshoot the problem. Note, enabling the setting will log *everything* ".. including all message contents, and can generate large logs quickly". BTW, what version of CF - Standard or Enterprise?

Comment: Thanks you all, Problem was, I have used the same SMTP authenticationemail(sushilk@domain.com) and to same email(sushilk@domain.com) I was sending the mail.

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet it's a server configuration that rejecting you and not a Coldfusion error.

You can test by using TELNET to the SMTP host - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995718(v=exchg.65).aspx